# Angular JS unit testing tutorials with examples

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to karma-jasmine unit testing for Angular js. So guys please can u share good tutorials?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First of all, and most IMPORTANT:**

> Unit-testing is similar in all other languages.
>
> You have to keep in mind the main features of writing testable code.
>
> Note: There is a good Pluralsight video ( Which cost money ) by Misko Hevery on Writing Testable Code).

**First: Watch this youtube by Vojta Jina - [Installing and Starting Karma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVw8N3hTfCI), the person who wrote karma.**

**Second: Watch this 1 Hour tutorial which I highly recommand : [Introduction to AngularJS Unit Testing By Jim Levin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDB-jm8MWro)**

After you complete those you should be able to test every piece of code in your Angular Project.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 8):

I've written a number of tutorials detailing how to get up and running with Karma and Jasmine for Unit Testing in AngularJS. I've also written a series of posts detailing ngMock in depth, which is Angular's own module that provides support for testing controllers, services etc in isolation.

Here's a link to a page that lists all these articles: [AngularJS Unit Testing Tutorials](http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/angularjs-unit-testing/)

Comment: I have read your series of articles which covers the angularJS Testing....very good

Answer (score 0):

There is an amazing documentation on Jasmine Testing provided by Angular IO on their official website.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

Good Luck